# How to create spaced text fields with a description of the text field at the top of each text field

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I was wondering how can I create spaced text fields and also add a name on top of each text field. Any help would be appreciated.

The code I have written so far.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AddContact" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter name" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter number" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Name"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter name" >
</EditText>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Number"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter number" >
</EditText
```

> The above code will help you

Answer (score 1):

hope the following code will help you,
You have to place TextView in between EditText to give reference,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AddContact" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Name"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter name" >
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Number"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter number" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```